# When do projection maps of polyhedra factor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

Given three polyhedra $P$, $Q$, and $R$ in dimensions $a$, $b$, and $c$ respectively, with $a\leq b\leq c$, with the additional condition that: $P=\pi_1(Q)=\pi_2(R)$, where $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are projection maps. Then

> ***Main Question***: When is it true that there is a projection map $\pi$ with $Q=\pi(R)$?

(1) What if we consider only (bounded) polytopes?

(2) What if we further restrict to just convex cases?

Comment: Roll-back if my clarifications were too heavy-handed.